# How can I play Parmen on Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, parmen

I've had [Parmen](http://www.parmen.com/) installed on my computer for a few days now.  Playing it went well for a couple short sessions in the first couple days.  However, today, it has started to crash whenever I select a square.  This behavior persists even after an un-install and re-install.  Otherwise, this system appears to be operating normally.

Are there some particular things I should be doing (compatibility settings, virtualization, etc.) which will ensure stable performance of this program?  I've tried setting "Compatibility Mode" all the way down to "Windows 95", and just about everything in between, to no avail.

System specs are below, taken from `msinfo32`:

- OS:  Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1
- Make/Model:  HP EliteBook 8530p
- CPU:  Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 @ 2.26 GHz
- Total RAM:  4 GB
- Video Adapter:  ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650
- Video Memory:  256 MB (Dedicated)
- Video Driver Version:  8.632.1.2000
- Desktop Resolution:  1280x800 @ 59 Hz, 32-bit depth

Also, I don't know if the game uses it or not but, I'm currently running DirectX 11 according to `dxdiag`.

Comment: Hey Iszi. Could we get some more details? Like the sytem reqs for Parmen, and perhaps your system specs? (other than windows which you have provided of course) Also try updating your video card drivers, which should pretty much always be step one when something goes wrong graphically in a game.

Comment: @Ender I can't find system requirements for Parmen on the website or in any included documentation.  I'll post my system specs shortly.  Parmen appears to be designed for older systems, but the EXE is dated November 2010.

Comment: I did some checking around on my graphics drivers.  They might not be ATI's latest and greatest, but they're the latest available (maybe even slightly higher) from HP.

Comment: if their not the latest then update them. what reason would you have not to? It cant hurt, and you would be suprised at how often it helps.

Comment: @Ender He could have a reason not to if he's running a laptop.  It's been my experience that for most laptops you actually need to run the drivers provided by the laptop manufacturer in order to ensure full compatibility with the system.

Comment: Is there an error code or any other report when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround - when the 3D screen appears, click either one of the blue attack board stems.  Click anywhere else and Parmen will complain, then go ahead and start your 3D game. I found that this morning, and it should help me track down what's going on.

Temporary debug file -> http://www.parmen.com/ParmenSetupV290D.exe

That release contains two openGl dlls that may or may not be necessary.  One way or another just copy the parmen executable over the old version.